# @property decorator just as a setter

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class of employer that receives structured data and provides properties to access these. I would LIKE to have a setter (without a corresponding getter) for the data input, and multiple getters (without setters) for accessing the properties.

Property decorators allow something like this

```
class employer:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.pName = ""
        self.pSurname = ""
    
    @property
    def Name (self):
        return self.pName
 
    @Name.setter
    def Name(self,lstName):
        self.pName = lstName[0]
        self.pSurname = lstName[1]
```

However, ideally I would like something like this:

```
class employer:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.pName = ""
        self.pSurname = ""
    
    @property
    def Name (self):
        return self.pName
 
    @InputData.setter
    def InputData(self,lstName):
        self.pName = lstName[0]
        self.pSurname = lstName[1]
```

That doesn't seem to be possible, though.

In short: Is there a way to create a setter without a corresponding Getter using property decorators?